# Why do the Russians call the Soyuz launcher the same name as the Soyuz capsule?

Tags: soyuz-spacecraft, terminology, russia, soyuz-launcher

It is sometimes confusing that the Russians call the booster rocket Soyuz, and the payload Soyuz.

Is there a reason for this naming model?

Reading Anatloy Zak's book he notes several proposed launchers/payloads that would have followed the same model (Rus-M was one I think) but does not propose an explanation as to why they would do that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is a common situation of the early Soviet program. The rockets themselves didn't have names at all initially. Only top secret internal indexes and project designations. (The spacecrafts often didn't have names too, btw. The public names have often been assigned only after a successful launch. See the stories of Vostok/Zenit, Almaz/Salyut etc).

The whole [R7 rocket family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-7_%28rocket_family%29) (such as Molnia, Soyuz, Vostok) is named after their spacecrafts.

The [UR-500 rocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Rocket) have got its name only after serving as the vehicle for the [Proton satellite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_satellite).

Comment: I've just realized that the brand new Soyuz-2.1V rocket launched yesterday could have been called Aist (Stork) because that's the name of the satellite. Unfortunately the times have changed and it doesn't seem to work that way anymore.

Comment: Now Soyuz is a brand name, with excellent name recognition and high reliability to boot.  Even if the Soyuz-2 had nothing in common with the Soyuz, you would still want to call it Soyuz for marketing reasons.  Good capitalists these russkies.

Comment: @MarkAdler Google Translate tells me that Angara means "shed" and that Rokot, which one could've guessed meant rocket, means "boom". They need to work on their launcher brand naming.

Comment: No, not "shed" at all. While there is a Russian word form "ангара" meaning genitive "of shed". The stress is different and it is clearly an accidental homonym. Angara rather refers to the river https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angara_River